# In Solidity, why use 'is' keyword, not 'extends' for inheritence

Tags: solidity

I'm looking solidity's syntax to use ethereum.

Then I see there is `is`, a keyword for inheritance.

I became curious about that. Why do they use `is`, not `extends`;
I think there is no association between 'is' and inheritance.

Isn't there anyone to know the reason?

Comment: Because in proper object oriented designs, [inheritance really should be an "is a" relationship](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php), so why not?

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right, thanks to let me know